# Devise not handling sanitized parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

The following console information

```
Started POST "/users" for 
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"==", "user"=>{[...], "email_contact"=>"5@mail.ne", "cap"=>"", "client_retail"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Unpermitted parameters: :email_contact, :client_retail
```

is baffling, as the two unpermitted parameters *(they were created subsequently to the original version, but the db was dropped, recreated and migrated)* are stubbornly being ignored (while the user is getting created.
UsersController does include these attributes

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, [...] :internal, :client_retail, :email_contact)
end
```

as does RegistrationsController:

```
private

def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, [...] :internal, :client_retail, :email_contact)
end

def account_update_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, [...] :internal, :client_retail, :email_contact)
end
```

In addition, the ApplicationController invokes the sanitizer

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation,  :nome, :cognome, :email_contact, :client_retail])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :password, :password_confirmation])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
end
```

Oddly, those two attributes **will** get processed under the update action, although not listed in the sanitizer.

How can these parameters be allowed?

Comment: Is your RegistrationsController like this? class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController end did you set the routes correctly? devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}


This route may change depending on where is your custom RegistrationsController located

Comment: with the route as `devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'sessions' }`  the normal functions run, but calling a new registration returns error `Unable to autoload constant Users::RegistrationsController, expected /Volumes/Mor/ph/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb to define it` the controller is in that path.

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell  My excuses.  The issue was a cache error from my text editor, calling up the contents of a different registrations_controller.rb file from a previous iteration (similar same name of application).

Answer (score 1):

Rename your controller to `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` or `RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` depending on where your custom RegistrationsController is located.